# Renderer/Sorting optimization

Tags: java, sorting, optimization, renderer

Okay here is the problem:

1. i do have a list of Objects that does need to be updated by the time since the last frame
2. the list need to be ordered by the y koordinate of the Object before they get draw

Current i do this with a collection.sort and a simple comperator:

```
figureComperator = new Comparator<Actor>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Actor o1, Actor o2) {
        return (int) o2.getY() - (int) o1.getY();
    }
};
```

The render does look like this:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // clearing
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // act the character act in front
    this.character.myAct(delta);
    updateGameCam();
    if (this.status == GameStatus.GAME) {
        // just monster act now
        this.figureStage.act();
    }
    this.figureStage.getActors().sort(figureComperator); // sort figures
    // render background
    this.map.drawBackground(); // draw background
    // draw figures inclusive character
    this.figureStage.draw(); //draw all figures
    this.map.drawForeground(); // foreground

    // render game HUD and act gameHud
    this.gameHud.act(delta);
    this.gameHud.draw();
}
```

So i am looking for a better way to improve the speed of this.

I do came across the idea of let the actors sort itself inside of the list(`figureStage`) while i do update those. But as i do the update forall with the `this.figureStage.act();` i couldnt do it that easy.

**So my question is, if there is any solution without having the complexity of an sorting algorithm to always have those objects sorted by its position?**

Comment: Can you keep the actors in a SortedSet so they are always sorted, and never have to be completely re-sorted?

Comment: Not sure because they do change their y-positions on runtime.

Comment: How often does that happen?

Comment: well that does depend on the movement of the monsters. So if they move up or down they change the order often. but if they move left right they dont. I dont really can tell how often because alot of the movement is random or its A*. Ofc i could just sort those every 1/4s instead of every frame for example but i meight look if there is a better solution. The player shouldnt notice that.

Comment: Does sorting the monsters take so long that doing it for every frame is a problem? If they don't change order too much between frames you may consider a different algorithm, insertion sort for example takes near linear time for data that's almost sorted.

Comment: Yea read that right now and going to try that. I just used the collectionsort because that was preaty easy to start with.

Comment: @Joni The default sort algorithm that is used by Arrays#sort and Collections#sort is already approximately linear for (almost) pre-sorted data. So I think it does not change much if another algorithm is used here.

Comment: Are you sure that sorting the actors is your performance bottleneck? You should maybe profile your application to get deeper knowledge about the performance.

Comment: Thats not right. Insertionsort is up to 3-4 Times faster then the regular collectionsort. No its not the bottleneck but it's one point where i can increase the overallperformance because every new figure or skilleffect does have an effect on the sorting. Any hints how i could profile it in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your Objects in an array (or list) of HEIGHT elements in size, where HEIGHT is vertical size of your world. Each element in this list is a list of objects with the corresponding Y coordinate.
When an object moves up or down it should be removed from one list and added to another according to its new Y coordinate.
This way you can just iterate the array and draw all objects in inner lists.
If Y coordinate is not integer you can use integer part of it.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Joni i started using a differend algorithm to sort the Actors. It does increased the sorting speed by around 2-3 Times just by using an insertionsort.

```
    public void sortList(Array<Actor> array) {
//      double starttime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 1; i < array.size; i++) {
            Actor temp = array.get(i);
            int j = i - 1;

            while (j >= 0 && array.get(j).getY() < temp.getY()) {
                array.set(j + 1, array.get(j));
                j--;
            }
            array.set(j + 1, temp);
        }
//      System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.nanoTime() - starttime));
    }
```

Average ns of the Collection.sort was ~8700. Insertion is around 3300!